# Can I use compiled class in Maven Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, compilation, classloader, maven-plugin

I'm writing a Maven plugin which has to use the project's compiled classes but are they include to classpath after compilation or i've to load them ?

Comment: The question is why do you need such a thing? Apart from that during the execution of a plugin the classpath contains depending on which life cycle phase all classes incl. them of your project.

Comment: Ok so the classpath include classes in target/classes ?

Comment: Yes. Depending on the life cycle phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different classpaths "active", depending on the current phase... e.g. in testing, the compiled classes are in the classpath. you can print them using [this code](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-antrun-plugin-1.5/examples/classpaths.html).